# terraform access variable using module variable key

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

If I have a variables in my terraform module, such as:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = string
}
```

within my module, I'm using locals to define some items specific to environments:

```
locals {
  dev = {
    foo=bar
  }
}
```

Within the module where locals is, how can I use the passed in environment variable to access the corresponding key in locals?

`locals.${var.environment}.foo` is what I'm going to, where `var.environment` will evaluate to dev.

Something like this?

```
local[var.environment]["foo"]
```

Comment: Are there any errors or have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the `locals` object directly. So this won't work

```
local[var.environment]["foo"]
```

And it will produce this error:

```
│ The "local" object cannot be accessed directly. Instead, access one of its attributes.
```

Instead, you can create a local map with your environments as keys:

```
locals {
  a_meaningful_name = {
    dev = {
      greeting = "Welcome to DEV"
    }
    uat = {
      salutations = "Hello from UAT"
    }
  }
}

variable "environment" {
  type = string
}

output "rs" {
  value = local.a_meaningful_name[var.environment]
}
```